# Using Marketing API to get post data

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

i am trying to get the post data by using FB's Marketing API, but the error comes up:

> KeyError: 'posts'

which is the 'posts'in line 6.

Below is my code, and i hided my id with xxx,

```
page_id = "id=xxx"

recent_2_posts = graph.get_object(id=xxx,
                                  field='posts.fields(type, name, created_time, object_id).limit(2)')

post_1 = recent_2_posts['posts']['data'][0]
post_2 = recent_2_posts['posts']['data'][1]

print(post_1)
print(post_2)
```

Would anyone please assist. Thank you.

Comment: Check whether you getting data in "recent_2_posts". It must be blank or it will not have key name "posts"

Comment: Thank you @VaibhavJadhav, i am following the article here: https://medium.com/@DrGabrielA81/python-how-getting-facebook-data-and-insights-using-facebook-sdk-9de14d3c12fb

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you getting data in `"recent_2_posts"`. It must be blank or it will not have key name `posts`